# Why is numpy inverse square root "x**(-1/2)" so much slower than "1/np.sqrt(x)" and "np.sqrt(1/x)"

Tags: python, numpy, performance

In numpy, the square root and power by 1/2 is almost indistinguishable in speed. However, when doing the inverse square root vs the power by -1/2, the latter is about 10x slower.

```py
# Python 3.10.2; numpy 1.22.1; clang-1205.0.22.11; macOS 12.1
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10000)

print("Square Root")
%timeit -n 10000 np.sqrt(arr)
%timeit -n 10000 arr**(1/2)

print("Inverse Square Root")
%timeit -n 10000 1 / np.sqrt(arr)
%timeit -n 10000 np.sqrt(1/arr)
%timeit -n 10000 arr**(-1/2)
```

```
Square Root
10.3 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
10.9 µs ± 321 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

Inverse Square Root
19.1 µs ± 744 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
19.4 µs ± 791 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
196 µs ± 5.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Can someone with more familiarity of the source implementation explain the difference?

Comment: The Python `**` operator has to be general case.  My guess is there is special-case code for +0.5, but probably not for any other values.  Thus, it is probably doing a general logarithm/antilogarithm thing for -1/2, whereas `np.sqrt` can be very targeted.

Comment: @TimRoberts `sqrt` probably goes to a specific processor instruction dedicated to finding square roots.  It would be interesting to add `arr**(1/3)` to the mix to see where it lands.

Comment: I think you're right. Take for instance `np.cbrt(arr)` vs `arr ** (1/3)`. Albeit, I can see why you don't want to check for 1/3 as it's a float with repeating decimals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`numpy` makes special cases of exponents in `{-1, 0, 0.5, 1, 2}`, but no others. There was [an issue opened in 2017](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9363) to add to add -2 and -0.5 to this set, but it appears that nothing yet has been done in that direction.